# Splash screen animation like linkedin in android

Tags: android, android-animation, splash-screen

HI I want to create a splash screen like linkedin android app. If you look closely the background moves at low speed and the text content and button moves at high speed.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code for splash screen

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginScreen.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein, R.anim.splashfadeout);

        }
    }, CommonVariables.SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME);
```

For animation

```
  Animation am = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.mainfadein);
  ImageView  i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  i.setAnimation(am);
```

mainfadein xml :

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1000">
```

In your case you have to make different animation xml file and animate accordingly each view.